# Should I use two single WordPress installations because of SEO?

Tags: installation, seo

I read somewhere that too many plugins can sometimes affect the performance of a website due to plugin conflicts, the way plugins were coded, etc.
In case there is some truth in this argument, I am wondering if the following website strategy can help to solve this problem:

- Create two websites in two single WordPress installations: Storefront (site 1), WooCommerce (site 2)
- List all the products ONLY in my Storefront (site 1) and from there send users directly to the checkout page of WooCommerce (site 2)
- Hide site 2 from google search engines since this site would only be used only for checkout and back-office purposes.

I am new to the field of web development in general and WordPress in particular, so any advice on this matter would be very much appreciated!

Comment: This won't work. You can't check out products from one website on the checkout of another site. I'm not sure I even understand how this would solve the problem?

Comment: Yeah, that was one of my doubts, but someone told me I could connect the sites using REST API, Redirection, or by using an iframe in my storefront site in order to do the checkout from there. As for the SEO problem, this would allow me to focus only on the SEO of my storefront, which would have only a few plugins installed.

Comment: How do you expect your storefront to work without WooCommerce plugins? You've misunderstood how this all works, or the advice you've been given. If you want a separate site for your storefront, then that's where all the plugins need to be.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding how this works. My idea was to create a custom storefront in site 1 (by displaying the products in WordPress pages), so I would not use the default storefront provided by WooCommerce. And from each product page in site 1, I would like to provide some kind of link to site 2 for checkout. Is this possible?

Comment: Having 2 separate instances can work and might make sense. But this is an extremely advanced topic to make sure it works 100% in all cases. The "too many plugins slow down site" advice is usually meant to make people think if they really need something or not. I have multiple clients running 50+ plugins on Woo sites that perform very well without any problems.

Comment: I see no advantages to this, and lots of technical and implementation problems. This is not the solution to poor performance you are seeking. The complexity involved in doing this does not justify the result. Also having lots of plugins doesn't slow your site down because the number of plugins is high. It slows it down because doing more stuff takes more time. You can have 5 really heavy slow plugins and it'll be slower than a site with 100 tiny plugins, it's not the number that matters.